# Java class not working when i add ''public''

Tags: java

Simple question :
Why is it working like this

```
class MyCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This will be printed");
    }
}
```

but not like this

```
public class MyCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This will be printed");
    }
}
```

giving this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
at MyCode.main(worksheet.java:2)
```

Comment: is ```MyCode ``` outer class or inner class?

Comment: If you define a public class in a java file, the filename must be the same as the class name.

Comment: Eclipse should show you a red underline at (or near) the class name. The issue is that public top-level types have to be in files that match their type name. I.e. the public class `MyCode` must be in a file named `MyCode.java`, but yours is in `worksheet.java`. This rule doesn't apply to non-public types, which is why your first sample worked.